# Android Dagger2 Shared Manager Class

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using `Dagger2` for my Android app, now i want to create a manager class which provide some function to other module

So, 
Is `Dagger2` support any function or approach can let me share the Manager Class or just use create normal `Singleton` class and share with the module class?

Comment: you have to provide your manager class instance from your moudle

Comment: @SalmanAziz
so that is mean i need to create the normal Singleton class and just let my module method to use?

Comment: yes do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so that is mean i need to create the normal Singleton class and just let my module method to use?

Why would you do that when you can just throw `@Singleton` on your class and it'll be a singleton?

```
@Singleton
public class SharedManager {
    @Inject
    SharedManager() {
    }
}
```

Now you can use this class from any @Singleton-scoped component.

```
@Component
@Singleton
public interface SingletonComponent {
     SharedManager sharedManager();
}
```